Expand all method expands all records apart from the first one
I've added this button to expand all the records:
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="right">
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActiveTreeNode}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActiveTreeNode}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
        <Button Content="Expand All" Click="ExpandAllRateParts_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>

and in the xaml.cs:
private void ExpandAllRateParts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ratesGrid = RatesGrid;

    ratesGrid.UpdateLayout();
    ratesGrid.Records.ExpandAll(true);

}

The issue I'm having is that on the very first click, is that it will expand all the records apart from the first one. When I click it again, the first one will expand. I'm just not sure why this would be happening or what I should be checking?

What are those “records” to be expanded or collapsed? In your XAML fragment, you show only a StackPanel.Style and a single Button inside a StackPanel. Where is your tree, grid, or something else inside that panel? Perhaps you don't have to provide all of your code behind, but at least the XAML sample should be self-contained. Also, note that a tree node expansion has nothing to do with the Visibility.Visible or Visibility.Collapsed. Why would you change the visibility?

I had forgotten about this question. I didn't include the tree as I didn't think it was relevant since all the data is there. Also the visibility is to do with the button not the tree. The visibility is correct. The issue with this was due to a method within this page being incorrectly called twice that was causing the grid to be refreshed

The issue here was nothing with this part at all:
private void ExpandAllRateParts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ratesGrid = RatesGrid;

    ratesGrid.UpdateLayout();
    ratesGrid.Records.ExpandAll(true);

}

it actually worked and could even be simplified as:
private void ExpandAllRateParts_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RatesGrid.Records.ExpandAll(true);
}

The issue was happening due to a method within the view model that was incorrectly getting called twice, this caused the grid to refresh which is why that odd behaviour was occurring
